# Space groups and crystals. Simple example for the diamond structure

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I try to learn the basis notions in crystallography and space group. But I already fail at the beginning.

Let me give you an example:

Consider the diamond structure (space group $Fd\overline 3 m$, number 227). It is a face-centered cubic crystal where the basis (the position of the carbon atoms) is $(0,0,0)$ and $\left(\frac 1 4, \frac 1 4, \frac 1 4\right)$.
In this space group we have the operation $(x,y,z)\rightarrow (-x,-y,-z)$.

Ok, now I consider the point $\left(\frac 1 4, \frac 1 4, \frac 1 4\right)$, that means I sit on a carbon atom. Then I perform the operation named above and end up at $\left(-\frac 1 4, -\frac 1 4, -\frac 1 4\right)$. But there is vacuum and no carbon atom. So how can this be a symmetry operation?

Edit: before I wrongly wrote $1/8$ instead of $1/4$.

Comment: Well, that is because those 1/8's should be 1/4's...

Comment: Sry, this was just a copy paste typo. But with 1/4 I have the same problem...

Comment: See http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/large/227az1.htm for all symmetries.

Comment: Now I am totally confused. Using Jon Clusters link there is no $(−x,−y,−z)$ symmetry in the space group 227. However here http://cci.lbl.gov/cctbx/explore_symmetry.html and also here http://www.cryst.ehu.es/cryst/get_gen.html the operation $(−x,−y,−z)$ is indeed a symmetry of space group 227. What is right and what is wrong now?

Comment: Two things to consider. First, adding a basis to a Bravais lattice can change the symmetry - now that you know because diamond, while based on fcc is not fcc. Second, you need to find the axes and points of symmetry that apply to a given symmetric operation - not any random point or line will do. Here, placing one atom of the basis on (0,0,0) and inverting through it did not work. That just means you don't have the right point.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hm, sorry I do not understand what I did wrong. First, I took the information that diamond cubic is $Fd\overline 3 m$ from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_cubic#Crystallographic_structure). I do not understand what you mean with "while based on fcc is not fcc". Second, you say "you need to find the axes and points of symmetry that apply to a given symmetric operation". But your link (http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/large/227az1.htm) shows 48 operations. How can I see to which points they apply?

Comment: Fcc is a Bravais lattice. Diamond cubic is not - it is fcc with a basis. The less symmetric the basis, the lower the symmetry of the resulting space group. As for seeing which points and axes, you have to look at the crystal structure and identify them. For example, there is a 3-fold symmetry axis. Well, which one is it? You can't just pick one, you have to look at the structure and figure it out.